# Want to stop COUNTBLANK at last row with no data

Tags: excel

I am trying to use COUNTBLANK to count the number of blank cells in a column, but the function returns an extremely high value because (I think) it's counting all the way to the end of the worksheet.

I want it to stop counting at the first blank cell in the A column. Here is the formula I started with:

```
=COUNTBLANK(DbT!BZ:BZ)
```

I want to know how many rows have a blank BZ column AND a value in the A column. I also tried this function:

```
=COUNTIFS(DbT!BZ:BZ," ",A:A,"")
```

This formula works:

```
=COUNTIFS(DbT!BZ:BZ, "",DbT!S:S, "<>")
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to know which row contains the first blank cell in column `A`?

Comment: Edited question to clarify and add new attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not entirely clear on what you mean by "I want it to stop counting at the first blank cell in the `A` column," but if, alternatively, you're looking for the number of rows that have both a blank cell in column `BZ` and a non-blank cell in column `A`, as you also say above, then this formula should help:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>",BZ:BZ,"")
```

**EDIT:**

OK I think I have it now. It's an array formula, so you'll need to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER after typing it in the cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)),1,0),IF(TRIM(BZ:BZ)="",1,0))
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you prefer a slightly simpler formula, this works too:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INT(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A8))),INT(TRIM(B1:B8)=""))
```

It's still an array formula, so you'll need to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm using those two to mean the same thing; i.e., it should not count any blank BZ columns beyond the first blank A column.

That formula looks like it does exactly what I'm looking for, but it gives me the number 37. There should be about 29,000 rows with a blank BZ and a non-blank A. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that some of the blank values in `BZ` are actually spaces?

Comment: Would the `COUNTBLANK` function work if that were the case? I used this formula:

    `=COUNTBLANK(DbT!BZ2:BZ31225)`

To produce the number 29,683, which filtering confirms is the correct number of blank rows. Does the `""` work the same as the `COUNTBLANK`?

Comment: Yes. `COUNTBLANK` would count the cells with whitespace, but without some additional work, it won't consider whether there is a value for that row in column `A`.

Comment: Right, I'm saying, does `COUNTBLANK` work where `""` would not?

Comment: Edited one last time. I still had my test cells in there rather than your `A` and `BZ` columns.

Comment: I tweaked your original formula, swapping the placement of the carets and the quotation marks (and including the referenced sheets, which was my fault) and it now works: `=COUNTIFS(DbT!BZ:BZ, "",DbT!S:S, "<>")`. Thank you so much for helping with this!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your column A is empty after that first blank, you could do the following:

1. Get the length of the needed range

   ```
   COUNTA(A:A)
   ```
2. Get the range in the `B` column that's just as long

   ```
   OFFSET(B1,0,0,COUNTA(A:A))
   ```
3. Use this as range for your `COUNTBLANK`

   ```
   =COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(B1,0,0,COUNTA(A:A)))
   ```

If the first assumption is incorrect, you could use the row number of the first blank in column A instead of the `COUNTA` but I'll have to look around a bit longer for that one...